# Python multiprocessing: Pool of custom Processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I am subclassing the Process class, into a class I call EdgeRenderer. I want to use `multiprocessing.Pool`, except instead of regular Processes, I want them to be instances of my EdgeRenderer. Possible? How?

Comment: Are you trying to write your code to use multi threading this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Jesse Noller:

> It is not currently supported in the
>   API, but would not be a bad addition.
>   I'll look at adding it to
>   python2.7/2.6.3 3.1 this week

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

ctx = mp.get_context()  # get the default context

class MyProcess(ctx.Process):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print("Hi, I'm custom a process")

ctx.Process = MyProcess  # override the context's Process

def worker(x):
    print(x**2)

p = ctx.Pool(4)
nums = range(10)
p.map(worker, nums)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any hook for it in the API.  You might be able to get away with replicating your desired functionality by using `initializer` and `initargs` argument.  Alternately, you can build the functionality into the callable object that you use for mapping:

```
class EdgeRenderTask(object):
    def op1(self,*args):
        ...
    def op2(self,*args):
        ...
p = Pool(processes = 10)
e = EdgeRenderTask()
p.apply_async(e.op1,arg_list)
p.map(e.op2,arg_list)
```

Comment: You can't pass a class as an argument to `p.map`, you'll get pickle error.  The only way I've found around this is to implement a sort of custom `pool.map`....setting up and feeding the processes myself.  Unfortunately it's gonna take more lines.